# I want to create a user in kubernetes with username and password. I tried googling but could find only creating user using cert key

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am newbie to K8s and still testing things. I have got prometheus running outside my cluster. I am using admin creds to hit kube api server to get metrics in to my prometheus which at the moment is working fine.

I want to create another user only to scrape metrics. While searching, i could not find any documentation on creating a user with user id and password.

Also, we are managing our repo in gitlab with pipeline. Is it possible to create user using yaml config instead of kubectl as given in the documentation.

Thanks
Eswar

Answer (score 1):

According to [Prometheus docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/basic-auth/):

> Prometheus does not directly support basic authentication (aka "basic auth") for connections to the Prometheus expression browser and HTTP API. If you'd like to enforce basic auth for those connections, we recommend using Prometheus in conjunction with a reverse proxy and applying authentication at the proxy layer.

In the link above there is a step-by-step guide in how to set up a nginx reverse proxy in front of Prometheus.